# Arduino TFT LCD Data Logger

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, tft

Can I use Arduino TFT LCD Module ILI9341 as a data logger? It has an SD card slot at the back, I wonder if the data will be saved on the SD card? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: yes, you certainly can

Comment: Sure. If you plug it in to your Arduino and write a sketch to do data logging using the SD card on the TFT screen.